# Best web search method to found "template" pictures

Tags: google-image-search

**[recommended migration from Graphic design]**

When I prepare scientific presentation I frequently use Google image search engine to find suitable pictures to insert them on Impress slides (Libre office). I usually manipulate with them later in Inkscape to obtain best look.

I have **no problem** to find simple pictures (requiring 2 keywords), but when trying to found something more specific **(3 keywords and more)** the search engine **gives often useless results** (completely wrong images).

```
Example:

keywords: robot; running (good results)

keywords: robot; running; against wind; step-by-step image;
          each step more damage taken
          (nothing found - I know that such picture may not exist.)
```

Does anybody know about some better way how to find desirable pictures on web?
**For example does exists some web library of images which have multiple tags (like questions on stack exchange)?**

**Is there any better method to search for image than use Google (or other search engine) and keywords?**

---

*I am afraid that this question is **only partially on topic here**. If you feel that it do not belong here feel free to delete.*

Answer (score 1):

I rather like [www.search.creativecommons.org](http://www.search.creativecommons.org), because it

1) Gives me results that I can use (without or without alternation) on sites where I run advertising, and

2) Lets me type in a set of keywords once, and then apply them across my choice of image or media source (for the options they have available).